# Use az cli to return secret names from keyvault that start with a known prefix in a list

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

I have a script that runs az cli commands (in powershell). For example, i'm using a commands like this in the script:

> az keyvault secret list ...

I pass parameters into the script, one of which is the keyvault name. For a given keyvault, i would like to return all the secrets in the keyvault that start with 'app'. So for example, if the following secrets are in a keyvault:

app1name
app2name
app1password
dbpassword1
app2password
dbpassword2

i want to script to return a list that is:

app1name
app2name
app1password
app2password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To return secret names from KeyVault that start with a known prefix in a list:

In my environment, I have KeyVault and created secrets with names like  **`app1name, app2name, app1password, dbpassword1, app2password, and dbpassword2.`** as you mentioned.

**Portal:**
[image]

To get the secret names with the prefix 'app' and output as **`app1name, app2name, app1password, app2password`**, you can use the command below.

**Command:**

```
$vaultname="venkat0123"
az keyvault secret list --vault-name $vaultname --query "[?starts_with(id, 'https://$vaultname.vault.azure.net/secrets/app')].name" --output tsv
```

**Output:**

```
PS /home/xxx> $vaultname="venkat0123"
PS /home/xxxx> az keyvault secret list --vault-name $vaultname --query "[?starts_with(id, 'https://$vaultname.vault.azure.net/secrets/app')].name" --output tsv
app1name
app1password
app2name
app2password
```

[image]

**Reference:**
[az keyvault secret | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/secret?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-secret-list)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with  **az keyvault secret list** command along with some PowerShell filtering.

lemme share you a snippet below.

```html
# Set your variables
$keyVaultName = "YourKeyVaultName"
$resourceGroupName = "YourResourceGroupName"
$prefix = "app"

# Get the list of secret names from the key vault
$secretListJson = az keyvault secret list --vault-name $keyVaultName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --query "[].name" --output json

# Convert the JSON to a PowerShell array
$secretList = $secretListJson | ConvertFrom-Json

# Filter secrets based on the prefix
$filteredSecrets = $secretList | Where-Object { $_ -like "$prefix*" }

# Output the filtered list
$filteredSecrets
```

Comment: Thanks mate for letting me know, if this helps you can accept the answer so similar issues ca nbe helped thanks.